# Show which of these 2 functions grows faster?

Tags: time-complexity, calculus

N * log(N)
vs
N ^ (1 + 2/ sqrt(log(N)) )

What is the shortest way to proof that one grows faster than the other?

Comment: Use the derivative of every function, reduce the derivative to its limes (limit) for large N.

Answer (score 0):

It often helps to take the logarithm of both sides, which preserves inequalities because the logarithm is a monotonically increasing function:

```
log(N log N) = log N + log(log N)
```

whereas

```
log(N^(1+2/sqrt(log(N))) = (1 + 2/sqrt(log N)) log N
                         = log N + 2 sqrt(log N)
```

Since `sqrt(log N)` grows faster than `log(log N)` (take the logarithm on both sides again if that's not obvious), we also have

```
ϴ(N log N) ⊂ ϴ(N^(1+2/sqrt(log(N)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of N * log(N) = log(N)+log(e), and the derivative of N ^ (1 + 2/ sqrt(log(N)) ) is always less than log(N) + log(e) (I used a CAS for this).